# How to open file .hstras

Tags: file, gps, gis

I have a file in .ostras extension, this file was sent by a GPS.
We need to open this file here on my business, but do not know with what software I could?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the exact answer you are seeking. But since no one answered your question so far, I am just adding my 2 cents.

The file is more likely generated by the GPS receiver not sent by GPS satellites. If you are on unix machine, try `od -c file.hstras` and see if you can read any ascii characters. That may shed some light. If you are looking for a specific software that can read the file, it may be very specific to the GPS receiver you are using.